# Web2PDF not reading Javascript or Php values

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using web2pdf to print a few values to a pdf document. In the html, these values show but when I'm converting the webpage to pdf, these php/js values disappear. What can I do to fix this?

```
<html>
<body>
  <?php session_start();
 $variable = $_SESSION['getSessionVar'];
 ?>
 <span id = "name"><?php echo $variable ?></span>
 <button id="cmd" ><a href ="http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/convert"> generate PDF </a></button>
 ..tags closed.
```

When I run this script, the variable value is shown but the PDF converter is not picking it up. Is there anything wrong with my code? Else, what other web-to-pdf generator can I use that can pick up Php or JS values written to HTML?
Thanks!

Update - 
I can't seem to convert any GET/POST or SESSION variables in the php script to PDF even though I assign them to a html division. Also tried assigning php variable to js and using

```
document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML = "<?php echo #var_from_prev_page"?>";
```

However, I can print and convert php variables that I create on the page.

Comment: first php opening tag is not valid.
session_start() should also be before any output, So before the <html> tag
Also don't forget semicolon after $variable;

Comment: @Nicolas: why would the php opening tag not be valid? looks perfectly fine to me?

Comment: @Swissdude - edited syntax after Nicolas pointed it out. Please ignore further syntax errors. UPDATE - I can't seem to print any GET/POST or Session variables to PDF. other php variables declared inside the php file seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SESSION,POST and GET can't be show in your pdf.

the reason is pretty simple actually.

The site you are using is using the `reference` of the request to "Crawl" your page

So the session id they get is diferent than you therefore they can't have any $_SESSION loaded since they never browsed your site before, and they don't POST anything to the page since you are clicking on a  link and not sending them any data to send back to your site.

The only way you could acheive what you want to do would be to have some way to change your `ref` of your request and add some `GET` by clicking the `a` link and have something to load variables in your php script.

If you want to test this actually, What you could do is to compare `echo session_id();` output from your browser and the pdf you get.